# What are the variables $remote_fs and $syslog on SysVinit LSB header?

Tags: init, init.d, sysvinit

From: https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

```
    Add a block like this in the init.d script:

    ### BEGIN INIT INFO
    # Provides:          scriptname
    # Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
    # Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
    # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
    # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
    # Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
    # Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
    ### END INIT INFO
```

These variables are also present on SysVinit LSB header from scripts like "ssh".

Does anyone knows about these variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are [system facility names](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/facilname.html) in Linux Standard Base. They're not treated like shell variables, they're just special names allowing init scripts to depend on certain system states.

In particular, `$remote_fs` and `$syslog` are defined as follows:

> `$remote_fs`
>
> all remote file systems are available. In some configurations, file systems such as `/usr` may be remote. Many applications that require `$local_fs` will probably also require `$remote_fs`.
>
> `$syslog`
>
> system logger is operational.